# Set bold and italic to a word in itext pdf

Tags: fonts, itext

How to set bold and italic to a word in itext pdf.

for example:

"**Hello** *World*"

in one sentence

please advice me.

Answer (score 7):

Please check this one:

```
Font font1 = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, Font.BOLD);
Chunk hello = new Chunk("Hello", font1);
Chunk world = new Chunk("World",
new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, Font.ITALIC));
document.add(hello);
document.add(world);
```

Comment: Font Normafont = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);                                                         Font headerfont= new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.ITALIC, BaseColor.BLACK);                                                                                                Chunk hello = new Chunk("hello", headerFont);
Chunk world = new Chunk("World",Normafont); 
   
PdfPCell rd311 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(hello+" "+world));    table.addCell(rd311);               Its not working buddy

Comment: Did you get any error? if this 'table' is an object of PdfPTable then is it already added in your code (not shown here)?

Comment: Yes, i am not shown here. table is object of PdfPTable         PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

Comment: Is it writing any text from this part to pdf at all? if yes, then what is the text? Also please try `Font.HELVETICA` instead of `FontFamily.HELVETICA`

Comment: hi buddy, i solve my problem from below snippet..                  Chunk hello = new Chunk("hello ", headerFont);
   Chunk world = new Chunk("world",Normafont);
   
   Phrase p2= new Phrase();
   p2.add(hello);
   p2.add(world);
   
   PdfPCell rd311 = new PdfPCell(p2);

Answer (score 4):

stumbled across this question while looking for the same thing.  I think the existing answers are out of date for more recent versions of iText (Im using 5.0.6).  Here's how I was able to do it:

```
Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
phrase.add(new Chunk("Hello ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD)));
phrase.add(new Chunk("World", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ITALIC)));
document.add(phrase);
```

Hopefully this helps someone ;)

Comment: Oh wow.  I pulled the version up out of my pom assuming we were reasonably up-to-date but 5.0.6 is super old.  I'll update my answer or delete it after testing with updated version.

Answer (score 2):

One sentence:

```
var x = new Phrase()
            {
                new Chunk("Hello ", new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 11, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD)),
                new Chunk("World",  new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 11, iTextSharp.text.Font.ITALIC))
            });
```